# How to display different set of data in RecyclerView depends on user internet connectivity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, offlineapps

I have a `RecyclerView` when user is connected to the Internet,my app will fetch the `Json` using `Volley` and display to the `RecyclerView`.At the same time,the `Json` fetched will store at Realm database as well.

This works well when user is connected to Internet.So the main problem now is,when user is offline,I cant make request to remote server,therefore I need to display the data in `Realm` database,which data are stored since the last `volley request`.

This is how I set the adapter so far,to display the item that from `Volley Request`

```
List<FeedItem>items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        adapter = new adapter(this,items);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**What I tried so far,**

In order for me to know the network exist or not,I do the following check

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null&& activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

//check for network
if(isConnected){
  //a different arraylist(),or different adapter here?
}else{

}
```

So I stuck here,I have no idea whether I should to add different `Arraylist()` to the adapter,or have to make totally different adapter to display the data in `Realm database`.

One thing I want to make sure as well,I test my application in Airplane mode without get data from `Realm`,the previous fetched data is still display,is it `RecycleView` will automatically cache the data,so I no need the `Realm database` for offline?

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: you should add data in same list weather it comes from online server or offline db. It should be same as well because you have inserted same data to db previously.

Comment: @JunaidHafeez so i no need to check connectivity?or no need offline db?If need how it should be done?thanks bro

Comment: let me explain in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to maintain both supports (online/offline) is your app, the best approach is rather than checking internet connectivity, let the volley requests in all cases, if you get response simple show in your `recycler view`and insert into your `local database` as well but if you get any kind of error, (no internet, some server error, some other issue) simply fetch the data available offline. 
As the data from server and offline are same, e,g `Contact`. you can add it to same list in all cases.

Comment: this seem like make sense..I try this later.

Comment: sure. acknowledge if it helps you :)

Comment: So i handle the the case which dont have internet at `onErrorResponse` right?

Comment: yup. in the case, if the error occurs due to server or any other issue, you would able to fetch data from local db.

Comment: when user online next session,I just clear all the data in local storage,to prevent the storage keep running up,is it handle like this?

Comment: if you clear all the data once user online, what is the reason of saving data offline? what if next time user is offline?

Comment: Can u give me some suggestion about when I should clear the offline DB?

Comment: actually DB meant to give offline support to your app. Rest is depend on your app requirement and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your data types are same, hence use different Arraylist with the same Adapter.